# Containers not showing up in simple html page

Tags: html, css

i'm building a simple html page and I'm basically trying to get two div containers take up the full screen of the site. One on the left and one on the right. Both to take up 50% of the page. For some reason anything after the `body` line of code isn't showing up. Here is my mark up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Website Name</title>

  <meta name="author" content="Name" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />

  <style type="text/css">
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
  }
  .wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
  }
  .container-left{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
  }

  .container-right{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:#ff0;
  }
</stlye>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-left"></div>
  <div class="container-right"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

For some odd reason none of the containers are displaying. I thought that although nothing was in the containers they are still suppose to display with if the height and width were set. Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: it is working, 2 divs with colors

Comment: it is already displaying one above another

Comment: @Hash I have the same markup on this site --> http://tiffanyevansofficial.com/ and it's not showing in any browser

Comment: @user32447 don't forget to accept answers in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it to display like this, if its block it display below the first div. you can try it out by giving colors. I have used `flex` to give side by side

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #800000;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container-left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0;
}

.container-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #10B4F9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-left"></div>
  <div class="container-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user32447 i see 2 images side by side?

Comment: @user32447 i think u made a mistake in the `<style>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your closing style tag is spelt incorrectly.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us. You may want to mark this answer as correct so that people aren't trying to solve your question still :)